# Problema ao converter texto para decimal na deserialização do ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, decimal

Olá,

Tenho uma api em ASP.NET Core que recebe como parametro um objeto do raw body da requisição.

```
[HttpPost]

public HttpResponseMessage DoIt([FromBody]DoItDto dto)
```

A minha classe DoItDto tem uma propriedade do tipo decimal:

```
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Quando eu chamo a minha api passando como parâmetro o valor sem as aspas e com um zero a esquerda o meu ModelState fica inválido e com a seguinte mensagem:

Input string '0208' is not a valid decimal. Path 'valor', line 4, position 15.

```
{
  "valor": 0208
}
```

Mas quando eu chamo com o campo valor preenchido com as aspas, ou sem o zero a esquerda a API funciona normalmente e o ModelState se torna válido:

```
{
  "valor": 208
}
```

Ou

```
{
  "valor": "0208"
}
```

Alguém consegue me explicar por que isto acontece e como eu conseguiria chamar a API passando o valor sem as aspas e com o zero a esquerda sem causar um problema na conversão para decimal?

Comment: se o campo é numérico (decimal), pq ele deveria ter um zero a esquerda? atributos numéricos não tem isso, apenas strings. Se passar com aspas, acaba sendo convertido, por isso aceita chegar com o zero a esquerda, mas se o atributos é numérico, deveria ser passado sem aspas e sem zero a esquerda, afinal é um número

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual. Como é uma api pública que será chamada por centenas de clientes externos não posso controlar como os clientes irão chamar. Para fazer uma api o mais resiliente possível precisamos cobrir todos os possíveis cenários e um dos clientes chamou a api desta utilizando o valor 0208, não consegui encontrar um documentação que explique porque o "0208" com aspas é aceito e não o 0208 sem aspas. Então estamos tentando atender o pedido do cliente.

Comment: Olá @Thiago Jordan, boa noite, dei uma pesquisada nesse tema e encontrei esse tópico e achei interessante, talvez responda a sua pergunta: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345894/numbers-cannot-begin-with-a-zero-in-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345894/numbers-cannot-begin-with-a-zero-in-json) Espero que ajude.

Comment: Olá @JeanSena, muito obrigado pela pesquisa. Esse era o embasamento que eu precisava para para justificar o fato de não permitir que o valor possua um zero a esquerda no json.

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade, vc não passa um 0 a esquerda em um tipo númerico. Se essa verificação é tão importante pra vc, sugiro transformar sua DTO.Valor em string, e fazer os tratamentos numéricos depois de a requisição chegar na controller.